# install external chrome extension in mac terminal

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have built some extensions of Google Chrome. I have the CRX files and I kept them my local system which is MAC 10.13. I wish to install my custom build extensions through bash script, purpose is academic only. I have followed the instruction at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/external_extensions. But the extensions are not showing in chrome. Can anybody help?

**UPDATE 1**
I dont want to host my extensions to chrome web store. If required I can use my web-hosting to store the crx files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Chrome is in [Developer Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-dev-01) if you are unable to host your CRX in the Chrome Web Store. Assuming your CRX follow's Google's policies, you might also consider hosting it in the Web Store, and making it private. The latter approach could make it easier to privately share the CRX with your academic peers.